# java+cmd:classpath resource file not found

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

I have a spring application .. and my beans.xml is somewhat :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:queue.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL">
        <value>${queue.url}</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

my queue.properties file is in a folder resources. I have added the resources folder to my classpath .. When i am running the app in eclipse it runs fine but when i am doing the same in command prompt it throws an exception file not found!! Help

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the resources folder on the command prompt, too. Like this:

```
java -cp pathToYourResourcesFolder foo.bar.Main
```